# Keep Console.ReadLine always on last line

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

I have an application written in C# which takes continuously commands from the user via a while(true) loop and Console.ReadLine.

I also do have various background operations which report back via the console. View this simple example:

```
class Program
{  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Messager(1000 * 2.5f);
            new Messager(1000 * 3);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
}

public class Messager
{
    Timer Timer;

    public Messager(double interval)
    {
        this.Timer = new Timer(interval);
        this.Timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("message from " + this.Timer.Interval);
        };
        this.Timer.Start();
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I enter a command and a Messager reports back before I have pressed Enter the message from the Messager will be appended to my current line and the cursor will be placed into the next line. See this screenshot:

[image: The problem]

As you'd guess I don't want that. I want the current inputting of a command to remain always in the last line and have all the messages coming placed above that line. Just as you'd expect from such an application. How do I achieve that?

Comment: My only ideas are to only receive the message at the end of a `ReadLine()`, which is probably not what you want to do, or you could do something with `ReadKey()`, but that would probably get messy fairly quickly. I do think you could use that method to get where you want though.

Comment: I don't think it can be done... For once, `Console.ReadLine()` will scroll on Enter, and then the user could resize the window...

Comment: It's a console. What you want is an output window with a command input area in the bottom. Not the same things - at all. You can emulate that look by making a winform / wpf screen that looks like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer to my problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Messager(1000 * 2.5f);
        new Messager(1000 * 3);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Messager
{
    Timer Timer;

    public Messager(double interval)
    {
        this.Timer = new Timer(interval);
        this.Timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            int currentTopCursor = Console.CursorTop;
            int currentLeftCursor = Console.CursorLeft;

            Console.MoveBufferArea(0, currentTopCursor, Console.WindowWidth, 1, 0, currentTopCursor + 1);

            Console.CursorTop = currentTopCursor;

            Console.CursorLeft = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("message from " + this.Timer.Interval);

            Console.CursorTop = currentTopCursor +1;
            Console.CursorLeft = currentLeftCursor;

        };
        this.Timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is very, very difficult to do. You end up writing your own console input and output methods that every thread has to call. If any thread doesn't cooperate, it just doesn't work right. But it's possible using the Console API.

The basic idea is to have your common output function write to the console screen buffer, and scroll the buffer in code rather than letting the text flow onto the last line and scroll automatically. As I recall, you'll have to parse the output for newlines and other control characters, and handle them correctly.

You might be able to get away with using `Console.ReadLine` on the last line, although in doing so you risk problems if the user enters more text than will fit on a single line. Also, the user hitting Enter at the end of the line might cause it to scroll up. Probably best in this situation to use raw console input.

You'll want to become very familiar with [Windows consoles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Be forewarned: it's a lot of work. And probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. You can use the `Console.CursorTop` and `Console.CursorLeft` properties.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Messager(1000 * 2.5f);
        new Messager(1000 * 3);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.CursorTop = 0;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Messager
{
    Timer Timer;

    static int position = 1;

    public Messager(double interval)
    {
        this.Timer = new Timer(interval);

        this.Timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                var cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                Console.CursorTop = position++;
                Console.WriteLine("message from " + this.Timer.Interval);
                Console.CursorTop = 0;
                Console.CursorLeft = cursorLeft;
            }
        };

        this.Timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets complicated very quickly. If `position` is greater than `Console.BufferHeight`, it will throw an exception. Also, writing beyond the visible window will scroll the text, or cause the text not to be visible. And then there's the problem of writing lines that are longer than the buffer width, which will cause unexpected scrolling and your next output line will overwrite the previous text. What you propose can work in *very limited* circumstances, but it's not a good general solution.

Comment: I know :) it was a quick and dirty demo of the properties. If he wants an IRC looking input console, he should consider a user control for that