# Console command-line

Tags: c#, command-line

iam trying to programe command-line for server and i have some issues i dont know how to fix. I spent half of day of google it so i will welcome any help. (methode Get cares about commands)

```
static void Main()
{
  string p = "";   

  Timer s = new Timer(TestWriteMessage, null, 0, 5000); //testing

  while(true){
    Console.Write("[SERVER]>");
    p = Console.ReadLine();
    ReadLine.Get(p);
  }
}

//TESTiNG how it works when i receive informations from client and write them in line
public static void TestWriteMessage(Object o)
{     
  ReadLine.WriteLine("Client connected."); 
}
```

and what iam stuck on is that when server receive some informations about client so i want to show it in console so i use methode WriteLine

```
class ReadLine
{
    public static void WriteLine(string Line)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        Console.Write(Line);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("[SERVER]>");
        Console.Out.Flush();
    }
```

[image]

If anyone has any idea how to get that text from previous line or different way how to make this work i will be really glad

Nevermind already got it. Found it on this forum but different topic exactly i was looking for so you can lock this post.
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060048/keep-console-readline-always-on-last-line)

Comment: It's not clear what you're attempting. Do you want to write a new prompt after every time the client sends some information, and copy the partial command that the user typed?

Comment: Yes after everytime client sends some information i want to copy the prtial command that the user typed write incomming infmation and on next line write back that partial command that user typed

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Isn't the variable `p` in what you have listed the value you want printed on the `SERVER` line?

Comment: Do you want that test to just be pre-added to the line so that the user can modify and edit it before he submits again? or do you just want to print it as output

Comment: are you having trouble keeping track of what you had just typed in? or are you having trouble with the printing?

Comment: i want that line pre-added that user can modify and edit it before he submits again. Yes iam havin problem with keep tracking of what i just typed because my methode writeline works for example i wrote [SERVER]> test and that methode does delete whole line writes there text i want to show and on next line writes [SERVER]> and i would like to show it with that 'test' how user typed before text was printed